# Drools Workbech: How to store/ write rules to a Database from workbench?

Tags: drools

Is there a way or option in drools workbench to store the rules in a database directly rather in a file directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the new kie-wb or kie-drools-wb workbenches you unfortunately can only use the git as the backend.